# (No module named sqlalchemy) but why since I have it installed

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I am trying to run a simple python3 code that creates a Postgressql table

```
import os

from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker

# Check for environment variable
if not os.getenv("DATABASE_URL"):
    raise RuntimeError("DATABASE_URL is not set")

engine = create_engine(os.getenv("DATABASE_URL"))
db = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))

def main():
    db.execute("CREATE TABLE books (id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, isbn INTEGER UNIQUE, title VARCHAR NOT NULL, auther VARCHAR NOT NULL, year INTEGER NOT NULL")
    db.commit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I set the DATABASE_URL

However when I run it on my terminal (macOS Catalina) I get this message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "create.py", line 3, in <module>
    from sqlalchemy import create_engine
ImportError: No module named sqlalchemy
```

So I tried to install sqlalchemy and it already has been installed.

```
% pip3 install sqlalchemy
Requirement already satisfied: sqlalchemy in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (1.3.17)
```

Comment: It is possible there are multiple installations of Python on your machine. SQLAlchemy appears to be installed in 3.7, but whicch version is running the script?

Comment: There are and I ran the code as python3 create.py sqlalchamy is in python3

Comment: I mean, even multiple Python3 versions...

Comment: How can I check for that?

Comment: Give this a shot: `ls -l /usr/bin/python*`

Comment: ok I ran % ls -l /usr/local/lib and only found one python "python3.7"

Comment: Can you try this command?: `python3.7 -m pip install -U sqlalchemy`

Comment: Thanks that was the issue. not really sure what -m and -U mean but that part of the code works fin

Comment: `-m` is telling python3.7 to run the pip module as a script, and `-U` is there to upgrade SQLAlchemy if a newer version is found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is likely a system version of Python 3 for which SQLAlchemy was installed using the prior command.

You can ensure the module will be installed for the specific version of Python 3 you're using with:

```
$ python3.7 -m pip install -U sqlalchemy
```

`-m` is telling python3.7 to run the pip module as a script, and `-U` is there to upgrade SQLAlchemy if a newer version is found -- not an issue in this particular case, but a good habit to be in.

Answer (score 0):

I changed my python interpreter to the recommended one and it worked. Before I was using the global python version.